# Why isn't my java text game ticking?

Tags: java, game-engine

Hi I made my game like a text adventure that ticks for random events and such to happen but its not ticking. I am ticking in the run method, trying to get 1 tick per second. I am thinking it is because of the sleep method. Keep in mind I am a beginner and this is one of my first Java games thanks :)

```
import java.lang.Runnable;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main implements Runnable {

Thread thread;
public boolean running = false;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Random rand = new Random();

public boolean playing = false;
public String currentInput;
public String allOptions[] = new String[] { "gather wood", "build a house" };
public String unlockedOptions[] = new String[allOptions.length];
public String commonRandomEvents[] = new String[] { "settler moves in", "settler dies", "settler born" };
public String rareRandomEvents[] = new String[] { "plague" };

public int housesBuilt = 0;
public int wood = 10;
public int woodGathered;
public int houseCost = 10;

public Main() {
    unlockOption(0);
    playing = true;
    play();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main().start();
}

public void play() {
    while (playing) {
        printOptions();
        sleep(250);
        getInput();
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public void getInput() {
    boolean dontKnow = false;
    System.out.println();
    printText("wyd?: ");
    currentInput = scan.nextLine();
    currentInput = currentInput.toLowerCase();
    for (int i = 0; i < unlockedOptions.length; i++) {
        if (currentInput.equals(unlockedOptions[i])) {
            interpretOptionInput(i);
            break;
        } else if (currentInput.equals(allOptions[i])) {
            {
                printText("you haven't unlocked that yet...");
                break;
            }
        } else {
            dontKnow = true;
        }
    }
    if (dontKnow) {
        System.out.println("you dont know how to " + currentInput);
    }
    currentInput = null;
}

public void printResources() {

}

public void interpretOptionInput(int arrayId) {
    if (arrayId == 0) {
        // gather wood
        for (int i = 0; i < woodGathered; i++)
            wood++;
        printText("you gather " + woodGathered + " wood in the nearby forest.");
        if (arrayId == 1) {
            // build house
            if (wood < houseCost) {
                printText(
                        "you don't have enough wood. there is a nearby forest. maybe we can get some wood from there?");
            } else {
                wood -= houseCost;
                housesBuilt++;
                printText("you build a nice wood house with " + houseCost
                        + " wood. someone will move in, right? You have " + housesBuilt + " houses. You have "
                        + wood + " wood.");
                houseCost += 10;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void unlockOption(int optionId) {
    if (allOptions[optionId] != unlockedOptions[optionId]) {
        unlockedOptions[optionId] = allOptions[optionId];
    } else {
        printText("option already unlocked. ");
    }
}

public void generateRandomEvent() {
    int commonRandomEventInt = rand.nextInt(2500);
    int rareRandomEventInt = rand.nextInt(10000);

    if (commonRandomEventInt == 1) {
        int randomEventCommonInt = rand.nextInt(commonRandomEvents.length);
        interpretRandomEvent("common", commonRandomEvents.length);
    }

    if (rareRandomEventInt == 1) {
        int randomEventRareInt = rand.nextInt(rareRandomEvents.length);
        interpretRandomEvent("rare", rareRandomEvents.length);
    }

}

public void runCommonEvent(int arrayId) {
    if (arrayId == 0) {

    }

    if (arrayId == 1) {

    }

    if (arrayId == 2) {

    }

    if (arrayId == 3) {

    }

}

public void runRareEvent(int arrayId) {
    if (arrayId == 0) {

    }

    if (arrayId == 1) {

    }

}

public void interpretRandomEvent(String rarity, int arrayId) {
    if (rarity.equals("common")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < commonRandomEvents.length; i++) {
            if (arrayId == i) {
                runCommonEvent(i);
            }
        }
    }

    if (rarity.equals("rare")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rareRandomEvents.length; i++) {
            if (arrayId == i) {
                runRareEvent(i);
            }
        }
    }

}

public void printOptions() {
    printText("you can: ");
    sleep(350);
    for (int i = 0; i < unlockedOptions.length - 1; i++) {
        if (allOptions[i] == unlockedOptions[i]) {
            printText(unlockedOptions[i] + ", ");
            sleep(350);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= unlockedOptions.length; i++) {
        if (i == unlockedOptions.length) {
            printText("or " + unlockedOptions[i - 1] + ".");
        }
    }
}

public void tick() {
    System.out.println("tick");
}

@Override
public void run() {

    int maxTps = 60;
    double timePerTick = 1000000000 / maxTps;
    double deltaTicks = 0;
    long now;
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    long timer = 0;
    int ticks = 0;

    while (running) {
        now = System.nanoTime();
        deltaTicks += (now - lastTime) / timePerTick;
        timer += now - lastTime;
        lastTime = now;

        if (deltaTicks >= 1) {

            tick();
            ticks++;
            deltaTicks--;

        }

        if (timer >= 1000000000) {

            ticks = 0;
            timer = 0;

        }

    }

    stop();

}

public void sleep(int milliseconds) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public synchronized void start() {

    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();

}

public synchronized void stop() {
    if (!running)
        return;
    running = false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void printText(String text) {

    char[] textArray = text.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(textArray[i]);
        try {
            if (textArray[i - 1] == '.') {
                sleep(300);
            } else if (textArray[i - 1] == ',') {
                sleep(175);
            } else {
                sleep(20);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please get rid of all the irrelevant code. Post a [mcve] - all you need is the `run()` and `tick()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

You're not `tick`ing because you never start the thread.

Although you invoke:

```
new Main().start();
```

You invoke `play()` the constructor of `Main()`:

```
public Main() {
    unlockOption(0);
    playing = true;
    play();
}
```

and `play()` contains a loop:

```
public void play() {
    while (playing) {
        printOptions();
        sleep(250);
        getInput();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

and so the thread won't start until the loop breaks.

If you want these `tick` messages to display while the loop in `play()` is still going, you would need to execute that in a separate thread.

Comment: So what I did was I just added start(); to the start Main constructor. Would that be good?